# R string comparison

Tags: string, r, comparison, match

I new to R and try to bring together two datasets (here `answc` and `diagc`) based on matching contents. Since the string `"1 - Tester1"` occurs twice in `answc` I would expect the result of `answc==diagc` to return in `res` at least twice 1 (=true); See example below.

Where did I go wrong?

```
head(answc)
[1] "1 - Tester1" "2 - Tester2" "3 - Tester3" "1 - Tester1" "2 - Tester2"
[6] "3 - Tester3"
is.character(answc)
[1] TRUE

head(diagc)
[1] "1 - Tester1"
is.character(diagc)
[1] TRUE

res<-ifelse(answc==diagc, 1, 0)

head(res)

[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: I get `[1] 1 0 0 1 0 0` with your example, assuming `answc` is a character vector. What does `str(answc)` tell you?

Comment: `as.numeric(answc == diagc)` seems like it would work just fine for what you need - no reason to get `ifelse` involved here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback

The hint with the str() got me the confirmation, that the problem may have been in the data types -> I re-did the whole process with data from ANSI-formatted csv-files, read them with "stringsAsFactors=FALSE", and made sure that the relevant answc and diagc really are "chr". 
The second repetition got the the desired matches, and although I can't really point out the exact error I would like to close this question. 
Thank you
Christian

PS: Form now on I'll always check the encoding and the classes of the elements that are involved in a comparison/match...